# Dynamic Annotation and Filtering

Tags: python, django, django-views

I think this should not be complicated but i can't get it right.

How can i conditionally count the number of brands in a specific category within a queryset?

```
views.py

def get_brands(request):

    all_brands = brand.objects.values('brand_name','brand_category').\
            annotate(brand_proportion=Count('brand_name')/Count('brand_name',
            filter=Q(brand_category="brand_category"))#I'm stuck here

    return JsonResponse(list(all_brands), safe=False)
```

I am not sure to filter the brand category and count the number of brands in that
category.

```
For example: 

brand_category 'A' might have: Brand 1,Brand 1 ,Brand 1,Brand 2,Brand 2

Here, the proportion of Brand 1 in category A would be 3/5 = 0.6  or 60%

I can calculate the 3 using Count('brand_name') within the queryset, but how can i calculate 
the 5?

brand_category 'B' might have: Brand 1,Brand 2,Brand 3,Brand 4,Brand 5

Here, the proportion of Brand 1 in category B would be 1/5 = 0.2 or 20%
```

Answer (score 0):

regarding [django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset).

```
from django.db.models import Count

q = Book.objects.annotate(num_authors=Count('authors'))
total_authors = som([x.num_authors for x in q])
```

so I hope, I passed the trick.

Comment: Thanks for the reply,Is it possible to include the annotation within the same queryset so that it can be included in the same jsonResponse?

Comment: Also,will the ‘for loop’ scale well if it’s a very large dataset?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a good idea for large scale data